How to use Django AutocompleteFilter thtough 2 relations?
i have Django models hierarchy
class Workspace(Model):
    title = CharField()

class User(Model):
   workspace = ForeignKey(to=Workspace)

class Chat(Model):
   user = ForeignKey(to=User)

In Django admin at Chats page i want to filter them by workspace, but there are many workspaces, so i need select2
At Users page i use AutocompleteFilter (django-admin-autocomplete-filter package)
But it do not work at Chats page.
Questions:
Is it possible to use AutocompleteFilter in this case? How?
Are there any other solution to make Autocomplete dropdown filters?

Use the AutocompleteFilterFactory [pypi.org]:
WorkplaceFilter = AutocompleteFilterFactory(
    'Workspace', 'user__workspace__title'
)


@admin.register(Chat)
class ChatAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = [WorkplaceFilter]
It will follow the relations and thus list the title of the Workplaces and then filter with this lookup field.
